# Calling thread cannot access this object

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In my wpf application I have added a piece of code in the button click as below:

```
 private void btn_convert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkerMethod));
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
 }
```

Inside my `WorkerMethod()` method I have some code like the line below:

```
btn_convert.Content = "Convert";
```

When it reaches to this line it throws the exception as the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

I dont want to use Dispatcher as it freezes the UI.. UI should be responsive so I have not opted for Dispatcher invoke or BeginInvoke.

Please give me your valuable suggestions.

Comment: "I dont want to use Dispatcher as it freezes the UI" - if the worker thread will use `Dispatcher` from time to time, the UI will be responsible. I hope, that your `WorkerMethod` doesn't make batch UI updating. `btn_convert.Content = "Convert"` will freeze UI on a millisecond.

Comment: You can call async version Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, rather than Invoke

Comment: I think you are doing some heavyduty work in WorkerMethod not just the ui update. You should only update UI from Dispatcher.Invoke. I dont see why that should create a problem

Comment: Acceding directly to the view isn't the best pratice in WPF. You should use MVVM pattern. Look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81484/A-Practical-Quick-start-Tutorial-on-MVVM-in-WPF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I dont want to use Dispatcher as it freezes the UI.. UI should be responsive so i am not opted for Dispatcher invoke or BrginInvoke.

That just shows that you've used the dispatcher badly.

You *must* access the UI from the UI thread. That doesn't mean your whole `WorkerMethod` needs to run on the UI thread, but this line:

```
btn_convert.Content = "Convert";
```

definitely does. So you might want to keep your current code for starting a thread (do you really need to set the apartment state though) but change any code accessing the UI to use the dispatcher. For example:

```
Action setButtonContentAction = () => btn_convert.Content = "Convert";
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(setButtonContentAction);
```

Alternatively, depending on what your `WorkerThread` is doing - and if you're using C# 5 - you *might* want to use the new async features. That can make it easier to keep UI work on the UI thread, but it does depend on what else is going on.

Answer (score 1):

UI changes can only be applied by the main thread. You can check if the main thread call is necessary:

```
if (btn_convert.InvokeRequired)
{
  btn_convert.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => btn_convert.Content = "Convert"));
}
```